# Swift 3 JSONSerialization serialize dictionary contain \ character

Tags: ios, json, serialization, swift3, httprequest

I'm making a request to remote server using RESTful API. I create a dictionary then I use JSONSerialization to serialize it to Data. The problem is when serialize date time dd/mm/yyyy it automatically add a \ character. This problem may be due to the convert from Dictionary to Data or Data to String. I don't know exactly.

**How to remove this \ character**

Below are my code on app:

```
var dic = [String : String]()
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
let current : String = dateFormatter.string(from: now)       
dic["RequestAt"] = current
// others set key-value
do {
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: DOMAIN_NAME)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    request.timeoutInterval = 3
    request.addValue("application/json charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    request.addValue("application/json charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
    let d = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: dic, options: [])
    let str = String.init(data: d, encoding: .utf8)
    print(str ?? "NOTHING") // Same result as server's receive
    request.httpBody = d
    let session = URLSession.shared

    session.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, err in
        //handle callback
    }.resume()

} catch let error {        
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

But server-side receive below json:

```
{
    "RequestAt":"08\/04\/2017 11:42:03",
    ....
}
```

Thank you for your support.

Comment: Are you concerned about the backslashes or doesn't the server accept the format? According to the JSON specs slashes can be escaped

Comment: the developer of server-side feedback me this problem. This system already has an app run on Android, so I must correct this step.

Comment: Escaping forward slashes is perfectly valid so it should be corrected on the server-side.

Answer (score 0):

You could go around the problem by trimming the string.

```
current = current.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.init(charactersInString: "\"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to use Alamofire for making request. It just a temporary solution because It must use the third party library.

What I do now:

```
let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss"
let current : String = dateFormatter.string(from: now)   
let parameters: Parameters = [
    "RequestAt": current,
     ...
]

// Both calls are equivalent
Alamofire.request(DOMAIN_NAME, method: .post, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in
    //handle callback
}
```